# Permissions - could not execute temp folder - dropbox and java applications

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions, temperature

So I was having an issue with multiple application on my windows 8 machine. Dropbox would not start, or run on my admin user. I also run a Java application called "Five9" and it was having issues starting as well. I found this topic [Can't execute from Temp folder in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/642626/cant-execute-from-temp-folder-in-windows-7)
And decided to try sharing the temp folder with myself??? It worked... Why the heck would I have to share the temp folder with myself, the only Admin user, or any type of user on the comp?

Also, should the temp folder have the little square in the check box for "Read Only"?

Comment: This normally means you have sever system integrity issues.  I would use DISM and SFC to fix those problems, create a new user profile, then transfer the files from the old user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're the administrator doens't mean you automatically have permissions to things. The folder probably didn't have your administrator account in the list.

I'm assuming you used the sharing wizard when you shared it, which will not only create and give you permission to the share, but will also ensure you have permission to the underlying folder itself.

Instead of sharing it, you most likely could have just edited the folder's security and added your administrator account to the user list, and permitted full access.

> Also, should the temp folder have the little square in the check box for "Read Only"?

Yes, all folders will.

See this SU question for more info: [Folder keeps changing back to read-only. What permissions setup causes this in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/131119/folder-keeps-changing-back-to-read-only-what-permissions-setup-causes-this-in-w)